# Could you provide an example on "datatables.typescript.definitelytyped"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, datatables, definitelytyped

I just want to know what is benefit of "datatables.typescript.definitelytyped" package.

Also could you please let me know is there any site from which I can take help to create a application for data table?

I know how to create datatable from normal jquery-datatable and angular-datatable. However, I want to know what is the "datatables.typescript.definitelytyped" for datatable?

Comment: Well are you using TypeScript?

Comment: `definatelyTyped` is a TypeScript definition file.  It's not a library.

Comment: http://definitelytyped.org/

Comment: yes i am using typescript and angular. I want to understand what will be benefit of using definition file.

Comment: Specifically, if i am using DataTable then what will be the type of that  "DTOptionsBuilder" and other veriable.

Comment: Matty M, Thanks for the reply. Could you please give me what is the benefit of using definition file. dtOptionsBuilder which is the definition added. Minght it is very small but not able to get proper guideline to usin defination file to get started.